# HLS player for Windows 10

Tags: c#, aac, windows-10, http-live-streaming, windows-10-mobile

I'm developing a video player for Windows 10. This player has to reproduce an HLS and an AAC track simultaneosly.

I wanted to use the [AdaptiveMediaSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.media.streaming.adaptive.adaptivemediasource.aspx) class for the video track as it supports HLS. For the audio track, I was considering to use the [AudioStreamingAgent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/office/office365/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.audiostreamingagent(v=vs.105).aspx) class, but for this case I'm not sure if it will be the most suitable option.

Apart from this, these two tracks must be independent. I mean, though they have to be synchronized, the user has to be able to adjust their volumes separately, even to mute them, but I haven't found any control not even for stopping or resuming the playback (which I assume should be a basic control for audio/video players).

I have found the [MediaElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aspx) class, which represents audio and video objects so, using this class would resolve the missing-controls issue but I'm not sure its capability through streaming reproduction.

Another thing that I'm wondering about is if that kind of objects, apart from the first one, are supported from Windows 7 to 8.1, will they also be in this version?

Which is the proper way to develop it?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can't use `AudioStreamingAgent` in a Windows 10 Universal app since that is a Phone Silverlight type. Other than that, sorry I can't help.

Comment: Thanks anyway! At least now I have something to start from :)

Comment: By the way, the day I wrote the question, the reference about the MediaElement class remarked it was supported in W7, 8 and 8.1. Yesterday I took a look into the page again and saw it was updated: now the class is part of Windows 10 device family. So, the querying about if it would be usable for my purpose is out of question.

Comment: Keep scrolling down :-). It is supported on those earlier platforms (albeit with fewer features).

Comment: My guess is that I need to use the MediaElement to print on screen what AdaptiveMediaSource is getting. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I'm implementing the player using two MediaElements, in the same way that [Javier Suarez's blog entry](http://geeks.ms/blogs/jsuarez/archive/2015/05/25/windows-10-http-live-streaming.aspx) explains.

Answer (score 1):

Azure also has a Media Player that they recently released. You can add the code for this player inside of your app as well.

[Here is a tutorial on how to do that.](http://www.davevoyles.com/uploading-video-to-azure-media-services/)

A few months ago Microsoft announced the new Azure Media Services video player. Here’s the biggest selling point for me:

> Azure Media Player utilizes industry standards, such as HTML5
>   (MSE/EME) to provide an enriched adaptive streaming experience. When
>   these standards are not available on a device or in a browser, Azure
>   Media Player automatically uses Flash and Silverlight as fallback
>   technology. Regardless of the playback technology used, developers
>   will have a unified JavaScript interface to access APIs. This allows
>   for content served by Azure Media Services to be played across a
>   wide-range of devices and browsers without any extra effort.

**DRM**

Microsoft Azure Media Services allows for content to be streamed using DASH, Smooth Streaming and HLS streaming formats to playback content. Azure Media Player takes into account these various formats and automatically plays the best link based on the platform/browser capabilities.

Microsoft Azure Media Services also allows for dynamic encryption of assets using PlayReady encryption or AES-128 bit envelope encryption. When appropriately configured with capable platforms, Azure Media Player allows for decryption of PlayReady and AES-128 bit encrypted content.

**Please note that Azure Media Player only supports media streams from Azure Media Services.**

Comment: Thank you for replying! I consider this possibility and give you feedback whether if it's viable for my purpose or not. :)